# Customize SpringApplication's bootstrapRegistryInitializers by using spring properties

Tags: spring-boot, registry, customization, bootstrapping

Im using Spring boot 2.6.6, I need to customize *SpringApplication* for the field *bootstrapRegistryInitializers* to use custom HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory for AbstractVaultConfiguration class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(StandardsMicroserviceApplication3.class);

        Long ttl = null; // get here the value of property "vault.ttl" which should be provided by spring mechanism (@Value, Environment class...)

        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionTimeToLive(ttl, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(builder.build());

        app.addBootstrapRegistryInitializer(registry -> {
            registry.register(AbstractVaultConfiguration.ClientFactoryWrapper.class,
                    BootstrapRegistry.InstanceSupplier.of(new AbstractVaultConfiguration.ClientFactoryWrapper(requestFactory)));
        });

        app.run(args);
    }
```

However i need to get value from spring property (for example vault.ttl) to configure the *HttpclientBuilder* with right parameters.

Is it possible to get spring property value before running the Spring application *(app.run(args))* ?

Is it possible to configure the *SpringApplication's BoostraRegistryInitializers* field after running the application and apply it the spring context to be effective ?